# iOS view.hidden = NO not always working

Tags: iphone, ios

My viewController is receiving notifications from background threads and updates the UI accordingly.

Using this piece of code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.myButton.hidden = NO;
    [self.view addsubview:someView];
});
```

What I observe every now and then (2/5 times) is that myButton is not visible. someView have been added. If I press the area where myButton is it becomes visible.

What is the correct way of updating the UI like this when called from a background thread, I thought this was it but it is obviously not working as I expected.

Comment: You should take a look at where else you might be setting `self.myButton.hidden = YES;`

Comment: This code looks fine - that is the proper way to do it. I'd take a good look at other place where you set hidden to YES. Any UIKit messaging on other threads than the main one will cause all kinds of weird things to happen. Ask me how I know this to be a fact :-)

Comment: The button I'm having a problem with is starting out hidden in the nib. At one point in my code I set the hidden property to NO. At no other point is the hidden property altered. I don't think it is an issue of this not happening or it is being overridden somewhere else as the button is responding to touch. It is there, working just not properly redrawn. Also if I swipe my finger over the area it becomes visible too. If the property had been set to hidden somewhere the button would not become visible and it would not respond to touch.

Answer (score 2):

There is not any issue with this code, You should check that you are not hiding it elsewhere.

So just search for other part or your code where you have code `self.myButton.hidden`

Comment: And `self.myButton setHidden:`, just in case.

Comment: @yes , but according to his code, i thing he is implementing .hidden

Comment: I am having the same problem; I am setting it hidden in the code but when I do .hidden = YES, the buttom is not appearing

Comment: ohk.. check that your button is not nil.